# Is there a single Python module for working with multiple types of compressed files?

Tags: python

I know there are specific Python modules for working with each type of file compression/archiving, such as [zipfile](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html#module-zipfile), [tarfile](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tarfile.html#module-tarfile) or [rarfile](https://pypi.org/project/rarfile/). However, is there a module that provides a single interface for working with any of these formats? I'm thinking about something that would automatically identify the format of a file and use the appropriate module for decompressing/extracting it.